# Display data from data base in QtableWidget

Tags: python, postgresql, qtablewidget

I have this code gui QtableWidget

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
data = {'col1':['1','2','3'], 'col2':['4','5','6'], 'col3':['7','8','9']}

class MyTable(QTableWidget):
def __init__(self, data, *args):
    QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
    self.data = data
    self.setmydata()
    self.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.resizeRowsToContents()

def setmydata(self):

    horHeaders = []
    for n, key in enumerate(sorted(self.data.keys())):
        horHeaders.append(key)
        print key
        for m, item in enumerate(self.data[key]):
            newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
            self.setItem(m, n, newitem)
    self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)

def main(args):
app = QApplication(args)
table = MyTable(data, 5, 3)
table.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
main(sys.argv)
```

Who display this 
[image]
and i have this code

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="sammy", user="postgres", password="a",      host="localhost", port="5432")
print "Opened database successfully"
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * from conn")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   print "ID = ", row[0]
   print "NAME = ", row[1]
   print "password = ", row[2] ,"\n"
```

who display this data from data base

[image]

I'm Beginner in python
I want to display the seconde data in QtableWidget 
what i should change in 1st code to make data display or another way

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You could build a data dictionary from your SQL results.  Just mimic the dictionary of lists from the example

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="sammy", user="postgres", password="a",      host="localhost", port="5432")
print "Opened database successfully"
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * from conn")
rows = cur.fetchall()

ID,NAME,password = [],[],[]
for row in rows:
   ID = ID + [row[0]]
   NAME = NAME + [row[1]]
   password = password + [row[2]]
```

Then modify the QTableWidget code

`data = {'col1':['1','2','3'], 'col2':['4','5','6'], 'col3':['7','8','9']}`
to be
`data = {'ID':ID, 'NAME':NAME, 'password':password}`